# Why does my object is returning property object rather than the value?

Tags: python, collections, namedtuple

I need to convert my Dict to a Object, and for that, I'm using `collections.namedtuple`.

```
items = {'name':'blabla', 'car':'hahah', 'dada': 19, 'another':'options'}
```

This a dict for this example that I'm doing.. Now I convert:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Items = namedtuple('Items',items)
```

When I want to read name, I should call this way > `Items.name` but what I receive is `<property object at 0x0000000002C277C8>`. Why is happen?

Comment: Why are you doing is that ? Using namedtuple is not so easy, and make stuff harder sometime

Comment: Trying to implement flask_login in my system without using models, so I do not have object, I have a user data retrieval returning a dictionary, when I apply this dict(user) in login_user, according manual needs object and it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using `namedtuple` correctly. It returns a class, you have to create an instance of the class from your dictionary.

```
Items = namedtuple('Items', ['name', 'car', 'data', 'another'])
i = Items(**items)
print(i.name)
```